# What's the mean of "#define PACK_OFFSET ((size_t)((pack_t *)0)->data)"

Tags: c, pointers, c-preprocessor

There have a struct

```
typedef struct _pack_t {
    char tag[4];     
    int type;                
    size_t size;              
    size_t offset;           
    char data[0];           
} __attribute__((packed)) pack_t;
```

And There have a definition

```
#define PACK_OFFSET ((size_t)((pack_t *)0)->data)
```

What's the definition mean? And how to understand the pointer "0"?

Comment: It means the same thing as `offsetof(pack_t, data)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a preprocessor macro. It yields the offset of the `data` member of the `pack_t` structure. It does so by taking the absolute address of this member when the base address of its enclosing structure is zero.

With a non-NULL pointer, this could be done by declaring any variable of type `pack_t` then getting the difference of the address of the struct and the address of the member, both in bytes, something like this:

```
pack_t dummy;
size_t offset = (char *)&dummy.data - (char *)&dummy;
```

(But not only this is invalid as the two pointers subtracted don't point to the elements of the same array, but it also needs a superfluous local variable, which one does not want for various reasons. That's why this is cleverly implemented using a null pointer.)

(Don't be confused by not seeing the addressof (`&`) operator - `data` is an array type, so it decays into a pointer to its first element.)

Answer (score 3):

It's the offset of the field data in your `struct  _pack_t`;
`(pack_t *) 0` is the NULL pointer, of type pack_t.
Note that the field data has 0-length, meaning 'variable': it must be filled by some function..

ex: `memcpy((char *) packet + PACK_OFFSET, data, data_len);`

Answer (score 1):

Lets imagine a blackboard

Wherever the teacher sees

```
PACK_OFFSET
```

(s)he gets the board rubber out and scrubs out `PACK_OFFSET` and replaces it with

```
((size_t)((pack_t *)0)->data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not answering your question and I just give a example to support H2CO3 opinion.To get the   offset of a member of a structure correctly, it must be 0 pointer.Here is code:

```
typedef struct _pack_t {
    char tag[4];     
    int type;                
    size_t size;              
    size_t offset;           
    char data[0];           
}pack_t;

#define OFFSET_0 ((size_t)((pack_t *) 0)->data)
#define OFFSET_1 ((size_t)((pack_t *) 1)->data)
#define OFFSET_2 ((size_t)((pack_t *) 2)->data)

int main(void){

    printf("%lu\n", OFFSET_0);
    printf("%lu\n", OFFSET_1);
    printf("%lu\n", OFFSET_2);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
24
25
26
```